# How do I find duplicates in a list for my specific game?

Tags: python, duplicates

So I've been writing this hangman code and it's pretty much done except for 1 problem. If there are multiple of the same letter in a word, only 1 of the letter appends. How do I make it so it appends all of the letters?

Code:

```
import getpass

hangman_pics = ['''
    +---+
        |
        |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
        |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
    |   |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|   |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|\  |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|\  |
   /    |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
       ===''']

let_list = []
word_list = []
alreadyGuessed = []
correctGuessed = []
falseGuessed = []
statusList = []

def player_input():
    word_input = getpass.getpass("Choose the word: ")
    for letter in word_input:
        let_list.append(letter)


def get_status():
    theStar = '_'
    for x in range(len(let_list)):
        statusList.append(theStar)
    while len(let_list) < len(statusList):  
        statusList.pop()


def player_guess():
    while let_list:
        print (hangman_pics[len(falseGuessed)]) #Got this from the tutorial
        print ("Please enter your guess: ")
        guess = input()
        if guess in let_list:
            if guess in alreadyGuessed:
                print ('Oops, you already guessed ' + guess)
            else:
                alreadyGuessed.append(guess)
                correctGuessed.append(guess)
                print (guess + ' is correct!')
        else:
            alreadyGuessed.append(guess)
            falseGuessed.append(guess)
            print (guess + ' is wrong, sorry')
        while set(let_list) == set(correctGuessed):
            print ('Congratulations! You win!')
            get_status()
            word_status(guess)
            return False
        while len(falseGuessed) == len(hangman_pics):
            print ('Oh no, you killed him! You lose :(')
            get_status()
            word_status(guess)
            return False
        get_status()
        word_status(guess)


def word_status(guess):
    if guess in let_list:
        guess_index = let_list.index(guess)
        del statusList[guess_index]
        statusList.insert(guess_index,guess)
    print ("The Word: ", statusList)

def letter_dup(guess,let_list):             #working on it.
    while let_list.count(guess) > 1:
        statusList.append(guess)
        let_list.remove(guess)



player_input()
player_guess()
```

Comment: voting to close as the question is asking a generic _why doesn't this work_. You need to have a clear, specific question for us to help you with.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your homework assignment. Try [/r/homeworkhelp](http://reddit.com/r/homeworkhelp)

Comment: @Blacksilver this is not my homework assignment thanks though...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you append every letter to alreadyGuessed once if it is in the word, and if that word has many instances of that same letter, then you wont let it be accepted. What might be a better solution is to just remove letters from let_list, and you wont need alreadyGuessed at all.

But there are more problems in your code:
Those while loops should be if conditions
also when you compare:

```
set(let_list) == set(correctGuessed)
```

it will be true for the word 'abba' and guesses 'a' and 'b', because

```
set('abba') == set('ab')
```